# Installing Core Arches

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install core arches https://arches.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/#install-arches-with-pip and I get the below error when trying to do the pip install arches. I am new to python and all I need is to install arches.

```
ERROR: Cannot install arches==5.0, arches==5.1.0, arches==5.1.1, arches==5.1.2, arches==5.1.3 and arches==5.1.4 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    arches 5.1.4 depends on psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
    arches 5.1.3 depends on psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
    arches 5.1.2 depends on psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
    arches 5.1.1 depends on psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
    arches 5.1.0 depends on psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
    arches 5.0 depends on psycopg2-binary==2.8.4

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 21.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Having same issue with installing psycopg[binary]

Answer (score 0):

run first
`pip install psycopg2-binary`
then run
`pip install arches`
on your terminal